# jQuery get href from link and output it as HTML

Tags: jquery, find, output

Not sure if that's the right wording, but basically I want to get the image URL from the link below.

```
<a class="attachment" href="image-url.jpg"></a>
```

Then create the following:

```
<img class="attachment" src="image-url.jpg">
```

Comment: when do you want to do this? is it when the user clicks on the link... and where to place the `img` element

Comment: You could use jQuery to grab `.attr('href');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**:

```
$('img.attachment').attr('src', $('a.attachment').attr('href'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace teh `a.attachement` element with the `img` element on page load

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('a.attachment').replaceWith(function () {
        return $('<img />', {
            'class': this.className,
            src: $(this).attr('href')
        })
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xX8LY/2/)

---

If you want to do the replacement on click of the link

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('a.attachment').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).replaceWith(function () {
            return $('<img />', {
                'class': this.className,
                src: this.href
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xX8LY/4/)

Answer (score 0):

> Use ***prop()*** in jquery.Get the value of a property for the first element
>   in the set of matched elements.

```
var imgSource =  $('a.attachment').prop('href');

$('img.attachment').prop('src', imgSource);
```